# How to scrape IMDB reviews

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, dataset, web-crawler, sentiment-analysis

I want to make an end to end project on sentiment analysis starting from data collection. For that, I'm starting with IMDB reviews, from this page in particular:

http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2137109/reviews?start=0

I'll be using scrapy for this, from the following code I can get the reviews and title:

```
import requests
from scrapy.http import TextResponse
import urlparse
from urlparse import  urljoin

base_url = "http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2137109/reviews?start=0"
r = requests.get(base_url)

response = TextResponse(r.url, body=r.text, encoding='utf-8')

title = response.xpath('//*[contains(@id,"title")]//text()').re('".+"')[0]

reviews = response.xpath('//*[contains(@id,"1")]/p/text()').extract()
```

The problem I have is how can I crawl the site to get a random sample?
I'm looking for a sample of 10k titles which I plan to get with in 5-10 days to avoid unnecessary hitting to the site and been baned.

There are some starting points like the top 250 [list](http://www.imdb.com/chart/top/?ref_=nv_mv_250_6): 
But I'm looking for a random sample.

Comment: 1) why you use requests, if you use scrapy? 2) Extract links and use random function for random sample

Comment: 1) I'm using request because I'm trying the xpaths on a notebook. From where can I take the random sample? I don't have a list.

Comment: Have you tried https://datasets.imdbws.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    **#All U.S. Released Movies: 1972-2016 #**

    from requests import get
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import pandas as pd
    df=pd.DataFrame()
    for f in range(4,101):
      print(f)
      url = "https://www.imdb.com/list/ls057823854/?st_dt=&mode=detail&page="+str(f)+"&sort=release_date,desc"
      response = get(url)
      html_soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')  
      movie_containers = html_soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'lister-item mode-detail')
      names = []
      years = []
      imdb_ratings = []
      metascores = []
      votes = []
      plots=[]
      genre=[]
      lengths=[]
      collections=[]
      starss=[]
      directors=[]

      for container in movie_containers:

        if container.find('div', class_ = 'ratings-metascore') is not None or None:
          name = container.h3.a.text
          names.append(name)


          imdb =container.find('span', class_ = 'ipl-rating-star__rating').text
          imdb_ratings.append(imdb)


          year = container.h3.find('span', class_ = 'lister-item-year').text
          years.append(year)

          m_score = container.find('span', class_ = 'metascore').text
          metascores.append(int(m_score))

          b=container.find_all('span', attrs = {'name':'nv'})
          vote = b[0].text
          votes.append(vote)

          if len(b)==2:
            collection=b[1].text
            collections.append(collection)

          else:
            collections.append('0')


          par=container.find_all('p')
          length= par[0].find('span',class_='genre').text
          genre.append(length)

          length= par[0].find('span',class_='runtime').text
          lengths.append(length)

          plot= par[1].text
          plots.append(plot)
          stars_director=container.find_all('p')[2].text
          directors.append(stars_director)

      test_df = pd.DataFrame({'movie': names,
      'year': years,
      'imdb': imdb_ratings,
      'metascore': metascores,
      'votes': votes,
      'Plot':plots,
      'genre':genre,
      'duration':lengths,
      "revenue":collections,
      "directors":directors
      })

      df=pd.concat([df,test_df]) 

      if f%10==0:
        df.to_csv(str(f)+"page.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the possible idea i can think of

https://datasets.imdbws.com/

and download the zip file named title.akas.tsv.gz

this contains all the tiles of the moveis in the imdb database write a function to select the random from the file and loop through the list

by changing the code to

```
    import requests
    from scrapy.http import TextResponse
    import urlparse
    from urlparse import  urljoin
    def random_list():
        #this should read the file and give random tiles in a list form once called.

    for i in random_list():
        base_url = f"http://www.imdb.com/title/{i}/reviews?start=0"
        r = requests.get(base_url)

        response = TextResponse(r.url, body=r.text, encoding='utf-8')

        title = response.xpath('//*[contains(@id,"title")]//text()').re('".+"')[0]

        reviews = response.xpath('//*[contains(@id,"1")]/p/text()').extract()
```

the documentation for imdb can be followed below.

https://www.imdb.com/interfaces/